# Typescript: TS2496: The 'arguments' object cannot be referenced in an arrow function in ES3 and ES5. Consider using a standard function expression

Tags: angularjs, typescript, socket.io

I followed some tutorials like http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/ to implement socket.io in my node.js server and angular.js client, everything works fine.

However, client side, Typescript display following compilation error:

```
TS2496: The 'arguments' object cannot be referenced in an arrow function in ES3 and ES5. Consider using a standard function expression.
```

Regarding following service codes:

```
on(eventName:string, callback) {
  this.socket.on(eventName, () => {
    var args = arguments; // <-- here the compilation error
    this.$rootScope.$apply(() => {
      callback.apply(this.socket, args);
    });
  });
}

emit(eventName:string, data, callback?) {
  this.socket.emit(eventName, data, () => {
    var args = arguments; // <-- here the compilation error
    this.$rootScope.$apply(() => {
      if (callback) {
        callback.apply(this.socket, args);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I tried different solutions, like the one described in the first post of https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1609, which fix the compilation but break the socket.io "on" functionality (the json objects aren't interpreted anymore).

Any idea how to fix or ignore this typescript compilation error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the `this`, **`arguments`**, `super`, or `new.target` keywords.

But you can use `function` instead of `() =>`

```
on(eventName:string, callback) {
    var self = this;
    this.socket.on(eventName, function() {
        var args = arguments;
        self.$rootScope.$apply(() => {
            callback.apply(self.socket, args);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: it's worth mentioning that the arrow functions don't bind their own this, arguments but use the one from the parent closure instead. MDN link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: that's why you can't use them.

Comment: Before posting here, I tried using "function" instead of "()=>" too, but I missed the self instead of this. This solution works like a charm, thx for the quick answer

Answer (score 13):

Another possibility is to use a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) instead of `arguments`:

```
on(eventName:string, callback) {
  this.socket.on(eventName, (...args) => {
    this.$rootScope.$apply(() => {
      callback.apply(this.socket, args);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: studied a bit about rest parameters from the link given and then this worked for me. cheers!

Comment: Very nice solution! I was looking for an alternative to the `function` declaration because the latter was always interpreted too early in my Angular project, leading to invalid service references.